# Must double-tap Windows key to open Dash

Tags: unity, 12.10, keyboard, unity-dash

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour of the Unity Dash and the Windows/Super keyboard key.

As far as I know, normal behaviour is:

- Tap: Open Dash
- Hold: Show keyboard shortcut overlay

However, the behaviour I'm experiencing is:

- Tap: Show keyboard shortcut overlay (after a short delay)
- Double Tap: Open Dash
- Hold: Show keyboard shortcut overlay

What could cause this, and how do I fix it?

I'm on a fresh 12.10 (Quantal) installation.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing unity?  [Refresh Unity](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1826936)

Comment: @iSeth I ran `unity --reset` which told me it was deprecated, then restarted Unity, but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer. It turns out that all this time, the "Sticky Keys" option in Universal Access was accidentally* enabled. I just noticed this with Ctrl behaving strangely, and now that I've turned it off, the Dash works as expected.

(* Or I enabled it on purpose, thinking to reap the rewards while not fully knowing the consequences)